# Angular Data Not Refreshing After Selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to refresh data every different selection. I made plunkr so you can understand what my problem is; This is some sample code:

```
$scope.change = function(val) {
    if (val == "month") {
        $http.get("month.json")
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.transaction = data;
            setTimeout(function () {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.transaction = data;
                });
            }, 2000);
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.transaction = [];
        });
    }
```

Its get the json data but not print. Why?

http://plnkr.co/edit/rReOwRuQXRElqBbXmpuG?p=preview

Comment: I've tried everything including $timeout, $apply(with or without it) but it doesnt help me a little bit.

Comment: You have two `ng-controller="transactionController"` which means the controller will be initialized twice with two different scopes.

Comment: That was the problem! So, thank you tasseKATT